# How can I display private nodes on full calendar and still let the dates/times show up as unavailable?

Tags: javascript, users

Okay, this should be easy but I'm not figuring it out.

I need to let clients schedule appointments for my therapy practice. But, obviously I don't want those appointments to be public. So I got content access and only allow the author of the session type node to view it, as well as administrator of course.

But now, it won't show up in the fullcalendar. So, it doesn't display as taken.

How can I have both results? I need those times to be shown as unavailable, but I don't want anyone to be able to view any session.

Comment: Okay so far I am using field permissions to hide all fields I don't want to be visible, and just leaving title/date as visible. This works for now. Any better solutions?